# 3d Plot on LaTeX with Random Element on Y-Axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am wanting to produce a 3d plot of the following function:

```
f(x, y) = x + x^2 + y * N(0, 1)
```

With N(0, 1) being a random simulation from a standard normal distribution. However, the difficult part is that I want y * N(0, 1) to be constant over the x-axis for any given y-value, with that value changing randomly along the y-axis.

I have the following code, however, the 2 issues being that I'm unsure if rand randomly simulates a normal distribution, and that y * N(0, 1) isn't constant across the x-axis for any given y-value.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function = {
    f1(\x) = x;
    f2(\x) = x^2;
    f3(\y) = \y * rand;
    f4(\x, \y) = f1(\x) + f2(\x) + f3(\y);
}
]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10, xlabel = $P$,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 12, ylabel = $t$,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 250, zlabel = $U$,
    colormap/jet
]
\addplot3[surf, domain = 0:10, y domain = 0:12, shader=interp]{f4(\x, \y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, I'm aware with the equation I've given there's no need to declare the equation separately, but the equation I'm actually graphing is a lot larger so I've set it up that way for simplicity. So, if possible, I'd prefer to keep this layout. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome. // Not sure what you mean by *constant*. // I suggest to add the missing lines which would make a copy of your code compile (start with *\documentclass* ...). // In almost all languages I know about rand() is just a cetangular distribution (throwing dice). You could approach N() by adding many rand()-calls AND normalizing them to 0 and 1. // Or you use a tool, R, which was made for this, generate a table with data and plot said data file with pgfplots.